# Python Error : CountVectorizer.fit - AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm getting error message from this command line "cv.fit (bigdf ['Description'])"

I noticed that this error is happening after I created the Tokenize function and RemoveStopWords sees that the line that returns in the panda is now like this

```
['PS4', 'SpiderMan'], ['XBOX', 'SpiderMan'], ['XBOX', 'Blackops 4']
```

before an entire sentence (here is the fit command is working, before created Tokenize(sentence) and StopWord(setence) )

```
['PS4 SpiderMan'], ['XBOX SpiderMan'], ['XBOX Blackops 4']
```

Is there any way to get the fit with tokenized values, or some way of converting these tokens to a sentence? Because I am using stemming and stopword library in Portuguese

```
def StemmingPortuguese(sentence):
    phrase = []
    for word in sentence:
        phrase.append(stemmer.stem(word))
    return phrase


def RemoveStopWords(sentence):
    return [word for word in sentence if word not in stopwords]


def TreatPortuguese(sentence):        
    return StemmingPortuguese(RemoveStopWords(Tokenize(remove_accents(sentence))))    


def Tokenize(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    sentence = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    return sentence

trainData = []

for name in files:
    if name.endswith(".txt"):
        #print(os.path.basename(name))
        trainData.append(pd.read_csv(os.path.basename(name), converters={'Description':TreatPortuguese}, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter=";", error_bad_lines=False, names = ["Product", "Description", "Brand", "CategoryID"])) #, error_bad_lines=False

bigdf = pd.concat(trainData)

print(bigdf['CategoryID'].value_counts())

print(bigdf[:2])

cv = CountVectorizer(analyzer="word") 
cv.fit(bigdf['Description'])
```

Comment: I think `sentence = sentence.lower()` is where it is going wrong. i think in this case, sentence is of type list rather than string. you can debug or print the type to check. a way to fix is to do a for loop or list comprehension like `[sent.lower() for sent in sentence]`

Comment: Ollie, i think error "Vectorizer should expect an array of strings. So if you pass him an array of arrays of tokenz, it crashes". As it was before applying tokenize rule and stopping the word. Just do not know how to fix this by pandas

Comment: I got. 

bigdf['Description'] = bigdf.Description.map(lambda x: ' '.join(x))